# How to create table without knowing the number of row?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm using JasperReports and facing a problem.
I need to create a PDF file with a table, but without knowing the number of its row.

So I decided to use JasperReports API without using iReport or Jaspersoft Studio to create .jrxml design file.

But, I cannot find any sample that helps me how to write code to use table (or crosstab) in Jasper Reports.
Can you help me?

Comment: iReport is just a tool to design jrxml files. I would suggest you to use iReport or Jasper Studio tools. Coming to your question, you don't need to know number of rows in your datasource, jasper report will handle and create rows/records based on the datasource. See http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/tables-and-crosstabs-jaspersoft-studio

Comment: @TuyenNguyen [HOW-TO Crosstabs](http://dynamicjasper.com/2010/10/06/how-to-crosstabs/) - the sample based on DynamicJaper API